# Changing default limit in Vaadin 8 lazy loading with grid

Tags: java, aws-lambda, vaadin, lazy-loading, vaadin8

I have implemented lazy loading in Vaadin 8 with grid implementation.

My backend runs on AWS Lambda which has a limit of 6 MB in response object.

The lazy loading implementation gives default limit(40) to server which makes my program crash giving error as "body too large".

I want to make changes in default limit of lazy loading in Vaadin.

Below is my code snippet:

```
grid.setDataProvider((sortorder, offset, limit) -> {

            try {
                return billingClient.getInvoiceListByCriteria(criteria, (long) offset, (long) limit).stream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Exception while getInvoiceListByCriteria", e);
                return null;
            }
        }, () -> {

            try {
                totalInvoices = billingClient.getCountInvoiceListByCriteria(criteria).longValue();
                Integer count = totalInvoices.intValue();
                if (count == 0)
                    Notification.show("No Invoices found.", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
                return count;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error occured while getting count calling getCountInvoiceListByCriteria", e);
                Notification.show("Error while getting count", Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return null;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Out of curiosity (as i think, that 40 items of something should not break things): is your billingClient there also fetching more than you need?  e.g. is it also fetching all the files involved with the invoice or is it ignoring the limit?  It might just be usual ORM nonsense and trying to fix this with the limit might just be harming other things (e.g. more queries just for folks with a big screen, huge traffic between your app and db).

Comment: The response object of billingClient is a nested list of objects with many items and taxes related to items. So its a huge object in itself and everything is needed.

Comment: Well then this is your real problem.  Don't request the whole object graph if you just need some Text to show in a few columns.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks. I will implement that. Also the limit problem is solved by manually setting the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by manually changing the value of limit.

```
grid.setDataProvider((sortorder, offset, limit) -> {

        try {
            limit=20;
            return billingClient.getInvoiceListByCriteria(criteria, (long) offset, (long) limit).stream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while getInvoiceListByCriteria", e);
            return null;
        }
    }, () -> {

        try {
            totalInvoices = billingClient.getCountInvoiceListByCriteria(criteria).longValue();
            Integer count = totalInvoices.intValue();
            if (count == 0)
                Notification.show("No Invoices found.", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
            return count;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while getting count calling getCountInvoiceListByCriteria", e);
            Notification.show("Error while getting count", Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return null;
        }

    });
```

offset is adjusted according to limit I have set.

Comment: Are you showing `Notification`s within a `DataProvider`? I wouldn't recommend that because a data provider is - as the name suggests - just for retrieving the data. Also: How does changing the limit to 20 in the fetch method solve your problem? I would expect Vaadin to behave errorneous when you do not return that many items as Vaadin expects.

Comment: Ah... I got your point in hardcoding the limit. May be I haven't encountered that scenario so its working fine. Regarding showing notification whats the problem in showing notification like this. What can be the alternative.

Comment: I would recommend showing notifications outside of DataProvider, for example when you set it to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Thats strange that 40 rows are larger than 6MB.

Never tried it but you can use grid.getDataCommunicator().setMinPushSize(size) to set the minimum number of items. It's initialized with 40 so I guess you can lower this to prevent your response from getting to large. But the "min" in the name suggests that also other factors may influence it, so you need to test it thoroughly.